# dropdown value not refresh in gridview

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am using a `DropDownList` in a `GridView` like so:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="drpstatus" Style="outline: 0" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%#Eval("status_value")%>'>
      <asp:ListItem Text="Inactive" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="Rejected" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

When I bind the first time it shows the correct selected value,
but when I change the value through another webform 
and refresh this page the value still remains same.
I checked the database; it *has* changed but 
it is not changing in the dropdown.

Comment: are you binding the grid under (!ispostback)?

Answer (score 1):

after you change the value, again bind the grid and check.

hope this may help you...and if not then provide more details